# How to find total amount from given ratios using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here we have one condition, here we have given three ratios for example 2 : 3 : 5(ratios can be change) and we have value of last ratio for example 5 = 10,000 so write a python code to find total amount.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some math

```py
# INDEX -3 -2 -1    
ratio = [2, 3, 5]
# INDEX  0  1  2

# let ratio to 2x, 3x, and 5x.

last_value = 10000 # 5x value
x = last_value/ratio[-1] ## finding the value of x

total = 0
for a in ratio:
    total+=a*x

print(total) # → 20000.0
```

OR

```py
# INDEX -3 -2 -1    
ratio = [2, 3, 5]
# INDEX  0  1  2

# let ratio to 2x, 3x, and 5x.

last_value = 10000 # 5x value
total = sum(a*(last_value/ratio[-1]) for a in ratio)
print(total) # → 20000.0
```